# Should I create an attribute to make camel-cased table names, spaced?

Tags: asp.net, dynamic-data, customization, camelcasing

I want to customize the headings of my tables outputted in a dynamic data website. Specifically, if a column has a name like "PhonebookManager", I want it to display, "Phonebook Manager" (note the space). 
Where should I be looking to get this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [DisplayName attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.displaynameattribute.aspx) to modify the text that is displayed for the column.  If you are looking to have these attributes automatically created for you, take a look at [this blog post](http://maddotnet.com/NewsBlogsJobs/tabid/150/EntryId/148/ASP-NET-Dynamic-Data-Presentation.aspx).  It doesn't do exactly that, but it gets you some of the way there.  (start in the Global.asax.cs file - look at lines 81-86)